# PyInstaller: drag-and-drop files to the --onefile exe

Tags: python, windows-7, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I finally got the PyInstaller up and running. So far it looks good, I'm able to create a single exe that does some calculations on the files in the directory where the exe is located. So I just copy the exe to a folder with the files I need to work on and double click the exe (windows 7).

But would it be possible to make an .exe were I just drag-and-drop my files onto and then it will calculate on those files  ***_*___**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to see how the files you drop on an executable get handled: build an exe from a file with such content:

```
import sys
def __main__():
    with open("parameters.log", "ab") as f:
        f.write(str(sys.argv))
```

Use it with one or more files that you drag and drop and observe the content of `parameters.log`: you should find that for each file its absolute path is passed as an argument. `n`th file will have its path in `sys.argv[n]`.

This can actually be generalised to any executable.

Comment: Somehow I couldn't make your code work, but it pushed me in the right direction. I can just use the `sys.argv[n]` as you suggested. Don't know if my problem was with the `__main__()` or the `open()`

Answer (score 3):

Late answer (5Y), but if you drop a file into an `exe` created with `pyinstaller`, `sys.argv` will receive a `list` containing the path of all the files dragged.
The first item (`[0]`) is the path of the `exe`, i.e.:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
['C:/name_of.exe', 'C:/the_file_dragged1', , 'C:/the_file_dragged2']
```