# Pyinstaller drag-and-drop files to the --windowed app

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

How do I allow files to be dragged and dropped onto the --windowed app and allow for it to be seen as a text editor/code editor by the system (Be recommended when you click open with and can have files dragged onto it)? [This question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712000/pyinstaller-drag-and-drop-files-to-the-onefile-exe) is practically the same to mine but since I am using mac it seems that the answer is different. I could not get the suggested answer to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the desired filetypes to info_plist of the spec file